# Laravel select left join all columns in new array index

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

i have one question in laravel query and search that in google and can't find that

**This is my query :**

```
$data = DB::table('event')
        ->where('TU', '!=', null)
        ->where('TM', '!=', 180)
        ->leftJoin('market', 'event.event_id', '=', 'market.event_id')
        ->select([
            'event.event_id as id',
            'TU',
            DB::raw('(TM*60+TS) as elapsed'),
            'markets' => 'market.*'
        ])
        ->orderBy('event.time', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

**and my result is this :**

```
Collection {#380 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#381 ▼
      +"id": 629
      +"TU": 0
      +"elapsed": 1200
      +"default": 1
      +"group_name": "other"
      +"api_updated_at": null
      +"updated_at": "2020-01-31 11:16:11"
    }
    1 => {#382 ▶}
    2 => {#385 ▶}
  ]
}
```

> **i want all columns from market table pushed in one index in result**

**like that :**

```
Collection {#380 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#381 ▼
      +"id": 629
      +"TU": 0
      +"elapsed": 1200
      +"markets": array:3 [▼
        0 => {#382 ▼
          +"default": 1
          +"group_name": "other"
          +"api_updated_at": null
          +"updated_at": "2020-01-31 11:16:11"
        }
        1 => {#383 ▶}
        2 => {#384 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**please help me for edit query in laravel**

Answer (score 0):

you can not use a field instead of many fields of one table in select. you can try use

```
->select([
        'event.event_id as id',
        'TU',
        DB::raw('(TM*60+TS) as elapsed'),
        'market.*'
    ])
```

or use `with('market')` instead of `leftjoin`